# Javascript game, connecting button as input

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating rock paper scissors with a user interface in html/css.
I have 3 html buttons for the choices:

```
    <div class="options">
        <button class="button rock"><i class="fas fa-hand-rock fa-10x"></i>Rock</button>
        <button class="button paper"><i class="fas fa-toilet-paper fa-10x"></i>Paper</button>
        <button class="button scissor"><i class="fas fa-cut fa-10x"></i>Scissor</button>
    </div>
```

My problem is connecting a click event on the buttons to input as the player selection variable in the playRound function. Can someone provide insight on how to accomplish this. I was trying to connect them in the userPlay function using event listeners. Thanks in advance.

Javascript:

```
// returns a random computer choice
function computerPlay() {
    options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissor'];
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
}


// should return a user choice
function userPlay() {
    let rock = document.querySelector('.button.rock');
    rock.addEventListener('click', setChoice);

    let paper = document.querySelector('.button.paper');
    paper.addEventListener('click', setChoice)

    let scissor = document.querySelector('.button.scissor');
    scissor.addEventListener('click', setChoice)

    var userChoice;
    function setChoice() {
        userChoice=
    }
    return userChoice
}




function playRound() {


    // defining the starting score
    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;



    // play 5 times per round
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

        computerSelection = computerPlay();
        playerSelection = userPlay()


        // game conditionals
        if (
            (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Paper') ||
            (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Scissor') ||
            (playerSelection === 'Scissor' && computerSelection === 'Rock')
        ) {
            computerScore++;
            console.log(`Computer: ${computerSelection}  You: ${playerSelection}   You Lost`)
            console.log(`computer: ${computerScore}   You: ${playerScore}`)
        }

        if (
            (playerSelection === 'Paper' && computerSelection === 'Rock') ||
            (playerSelection === 'Scissor' && computerSelection === 'Paper') ||
            (playerSelection === 'Rock' && computerSelection === 'Scissor')
        ) {
            playerScore++;
            console.log(`Computer: ${computerSelection}  You: ${playerSelection}    You Won`)
            console.log(`computer: ${computerScore}   You: ${playerScore}`)
        }


        if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
            console.log(`Computer: ${computerSelection}  You: ${playerSelection}  Its a tie`);
            console.log(`computer: ${computerScore}   You: ${playerScore}`);
            continue
        }


    }


    // ending score
    if (computerScore > playerScore) {
        console.log('Sorry, you lost')
    }
    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
        console.log('Congrats, you won')
    }
    else {
        'It was a tie game'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the events *inside* the function.

Consider using a data-attribute on the buttons and event delegations like this

```
<button data-shake='rock'>
```

.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    
    if ( event.target.matches('button') ) {
       runFunction(event.target.dataset.shake); // would get 'rock' etc...
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arrow function so you'd be able to pass a parameter to the function.

(Read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#event_listener_with_an_arrow_function)

```
let rock = document.querySelector('.button.rock');
rock.addEventListener('click', () => {setChoice("scissor")});

let paper = document.querySelector('.button.paper');
paper.addEventListener('click', () => {setChoice("scissor")})

let scissor = document.querySelector('.button.scissor');
scissor.addEventListener('click', () => {setChoice("scissor")})

var userChoice;
function setChoice(userChoice) {
    // ....
}
```